# Gradle: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradlew

Gradle build is throwing the following error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.oracle:ons:19.3.
> Required by:
> project :
> project : > com.xyz.abc.utils:openshift-utils:2.0.30

I have added the below dependency

implementation('com.oracle:ons:19.3')

Also the below repository

```
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'http://repository.xyz.com:8081/artifactory/gradle-plugins'; allowInsecureProtocol true 
   metadataSources {
        mavenPom()
        artifact()
   }
}
```

I can see this dependency under Project and External Dependencies
[image]

The project that is needing this dependency has the below line in build.gradle
compile("com.oracle:ons:19.3")

I'm using gradle wrapper and gradle version is 7.4.2

Can you please help in resolving this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar issue. This resolved for me when I used a compatible spring boot version for particular JAVA version you are using in your project.I was getting similar issue-
For example - version 3.0.0 is not compatible with JAVA 11
[image]

But when I used version 3.0.0 with JAVA 17 and rebuild the project, it was resolved
[image]